# How to set lines that GDB shows per command?

Tags: gcc, gdb

By default, gdb can just show 1 line source code per command, now I want to set it show 10 lines per command, what should I do ?

Answer (score 1):

> what should I do

You should *probably* use some GDB front end, such as Eclipse, or emacs. You could also try using `gdb --tui`.

What you are asking for is unlikely to give you productive debugging environment, and I don't believe is directly achievable. You could get pretty close like this:

```
cat t.c
int main()
{
  int x = 1;
  x = 2;
  x = 3;
  x++;
  return x;
}

gcc -g t.c && gdb -q ./a.out
(gdb) define hook-stop
Type commands for definition of "hook-stop".
End with a line saying just "end".
>list
>end
(gdb) start
Temporary breakpoint 1 at 0x4004f1: file t.c, line 3.
Starting program: /tmp/a.out 
1       int main()
2       {
3         int x = 1;
4         x = 2;
5         x = 3;
6         x++;
7         return x;
8       }

Temporary breakpoint 1, main () at t.c:3
3         int x = 1;
(gdb) n
1       int main()
2       {
3         int x = 1;
4         x = 2;
5         x = 3;
6         x++;
7         return x;
8       }
4         x = 2;
(gdb) n
1       int main()
2       {
3         int x = 1;
4         x = 2;
5         x = 3;
6         x++;
7         return x;
8       }
5         x = 3;
```

... etc.